# Get user location on app running as well as if app is in background

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm beginner in React Native, I'm using expo I want to ask user for permission to access location if user granted the permission it will check if phone location from setting is on or not if it is on then it will give it's current location and if the app is close or running in background it will still give location

I have tried but it's not working

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Platform,
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Linking,
  Button,
  AppState
} from "react-native";
import Constants from "expo-constants";
import * as TaskManager from "expo-task-manager";
import * as Location from "expo-location";
import * as Permissions from "expo-permissions";
import * as IntentLauncher from "expo-intent-launcher";
import { Alert, NavigationActions } from "react-native";
import Modal from "react-native-modal";

const LOCATION_TASK_NAME = "background-location-task";

export default class LocationScreen extends Component {
  state = {
    location: null,
    errorMessage: null,
  };


  componentDidMount = async () => {
    await Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(LOCATION_TASK_NAME, {
      accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Balanced
    });




  render() {
    let text = "Waiting..";
    if (this.state.errorMessage) {
      text = this.state.errorMessage;
    } else if (this.state.location) {
      text = JSON.stringify(this.state.location);
    }

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>{text}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

TaskManager.defineTask(LOCATION_TASK_NAME, handel);

export async function handel({ data, error }) {
  try {
    let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);

    if (status !== "granted") {
      this.setState({
        errorMessage: "Permission to access location was denied"
      });
      return;
    } else {
      if (data) {
        const { locations } = data;
        const location = locations.map(location => {
          let newLocation = Location.reverseGeocodeAsync(location.coords).then(
            data => {
              let maplocation = data.map(location => {
                console.log(location);
                console.log(location.city);
              });
            }
          );
        });
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    let status = Location.getProviderStatusAsync();
    if (!status.locationServiceEnabled) {
      const { navigation } = this.props;
      navigation.navigate("Login");
    }
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: "#ecf0f1"
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    textAlign: "center"
  }
});
```

This is only working if location is on. It's not asking for permission if location is off or not granted